# ARM NEON Intrisics: Is using vmaxvq_s16() the fastest way to find max value in a int16x8 vector?

Tags: c++, arm, vectorization, simd, neon

I would like to know if anyone has found a more efficient (faster) way of finding the maximum value  in a int16x8 vector, than using the `vmaxvq_s16()` ARM NEON Intrisic.

For example I was trying to benefit from doing some vectorized comparisons, but couldn't find a solution faster from using the intrisic above.

Comment: Please show your code.  Also, you might do better to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was hopping I would get a more general answer and not code specific, about the implementation of the intrisic from the compiler.

Comment: It's a real intrinsic for a single SMAXV instruction (at least on AArch64, I didn't check 32-bit ARM); https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vmaxvq_s16 .  Unless it's microcoded and the CPU architects did a bad job, you won't be able to do exactly the same thing but faster with multiple instructions.

Comment: Is the special instruction actually more efficient? There is a setup time involved in using it.  I haven't had the compiler use the special instruction even at highest optimization setting.  Compiler is IAR Electronic Workbench.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: GCC and clang both use `smaxv` when auto-vectorizing max of an array of `int16_t` (https://godbolt.org/z/74363z4cW).  The Cortex-A76 optimization guide with cycle timings (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/pjdoc466751330-7215/8-0/?lang=en) says it runs with 5 cycle latency but 1/clock throughput for 8x int16_t (8H layout), using both the V1 pipeline and any V pipe.  Reducing 8 elements to 1 in only 1 instruction for 2 pipes is a big win.  Using only vertical `smax`, you'd need 3 shuffle-and-max steps to get down to 1 element.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews with gcc and -O3 flag indeed it compiles as `smaxv`

Comment: It's worth noting in those examples that if you want to find the maximum of a larger array, you want to keep 8 running maximums going, so that you do one `smax` (not `smaxv`) per 8 elements, then one single `smaxv` at the end of the loop.  So `smaxv` is the best way to do the specific thing it does, but if you step back and look at your algorithm, that may not be the thing you actually want to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, the implementation of `vmaxvq` has quite a bit latency and doesn't even dual issue, but the typical alternative is even worse.

```
   a = vmaxq_s16(a, vextq_s16(a,a,1));
   a = vmaxq_s16(a, vextq_s16(a,a,2));
   a = vmaxq_s16(a, vextq_s16(a,a,4));
```

However ARM64 typically implements the pairwise maximum much more efficiently, allowing

```
   a = vpmaxq_s16(a, a);
   a = vpmaxq_s16(a, a);
   a = vpmaxq_s16(a, a);
```

If the original problem doesn't allow reorganisation for purely vertical operations, there's still a possibility to amortize the parallel max operations.

```
   // the two first elements here will be garbage
   int16_t buffer[N + 2];
   auto A = vdupq_n_s16(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       int16x8_t x = my_algorithm();
       A = vpmaxq_s16(A, x);  // <- just a single fast vpmax per iteration
       vst1q_lane_s16(buffer + i, A, 1);
   }
   // you need two more iterations to finish the pairwise horizontal
   // maximums that are partially stored in A
   for (int i = N; i < N + 2; i++) {
      A = vpmaxq_s16(A, A);
      vst1q_lane_s16(buffer + i, A, 1);
   }
```

Example run for two iterations

```
   A = 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,   v_0 = 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2
   A = 0   0   0   0   3   4   5   3,   v_1 = 0 1 0 2 3 2 0 0
   A = 0   0  3+4 5+3 0+1 0+2 3+2 0+0,  v_2 = ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
   -----------------
   A = 0  [15] 3   5.  ?   ?   ?   ?    [15 = 1+2+3+1+2+3+1+2]
   A = 15 [ 8] ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?    [8  = 0+1+0+2+3+2+0+0]
```

The first element `A[0]` will btw accumulate the total maximum of all the elements.